# Is a mqd_t of a POSIX-MQ a critical resource?

Tags: multithreading, system-calls, file-descriptor, data-race, posix-mq

I need to send messages through same Posix-MQ in multiple threads.

These threads **all** act as a "producer" of messages, while the "consumer" is another **process**.

Should I do `mq_open` for every threads respectively and use different `mqd_t` in different threads?

Or I can `mq_open` once, and use the same `mqd_t` in all threads?

Comment: You only need one.  It is good to look for confirmation; but it is better to experiment for yourself, then seek out whether your observations are *standard* or *implementation defined* behaviours.  If you have a programming environment that inhibits experimentation, you need a new programming environment.